# Quickie about app upgrades for blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Sorry if this question seems kind of obvious.

Last month I released my first app and now I have an upgrade for it.
The app is a paid blackberry (os5 - os7) app and i want to know if the upgrade will be free to users who have already paid for it.

My guess and what I am hoping for is the users who have already paid for it will be able to upgrade without having to pay again. And users who are purchasing it for the first time will pay.

The reason I'm asking this question is because I have seen reviews from other apps on blackberry appworld  where the users claim they had to pay for the upgrade. So it is because of this that I must ask this question just to be sure.

thank you

Comment: You can decide whether or not the upgrade will cost users.  Review the options when you add the new release to App World.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a option named `License Type` while add a new product to your inventory page of vendor account. That option allows you to choose whether your app's user need to pay for an upgrade or not.